# jquery checking if an image exists in a folder

Tags: jquery, image

i am changing the source of an image using the following code:

```
var src = "/Content/Productimg/" + data.image +".jpg";
              $("#image").attr("src", src);
```

However, sometimes if data.img returns test and test.jpg does not exist in the Productimg folder a funny icon is displayed.

Is there a way i can check if the image is there before assigning the src?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For checking if image exists or not , you can do:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'http://yourhost/someimage.ext',
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file does not exist
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists do something here
    }
});
```

Comment: While this might work for the op, it's useless in general because images are usually from cross-domain and even if it worked it's just extremely convoluted

Comment: More accurately "// there was a problem getting the file"; could be a problem other than file not existing. @Esailija pretty hard to say that if the questioner says "works like a treat"... Sudhir must be doing something right. ;-). Also, images are almost never from cross-domain...? Not sure where you got that from.

Comment: @GregPettit, content delivery networks? The ajax request will not do anything if no CORS policy is set or even if its set, older browsers have no idea of it.

Comment: @Esailija Sure, you CAN have your images on a CDN, but "usually" is very much an overstatement. I would say people keep their images "rarely" or at most "sometimes" on another domain.

Comment: @GregPettit, if you are just hacking around, sure keep your images on same domain. If you have a real website that people actually visit, then you better use a CDN... performance is a feature :)

Comment: http://sstatic.net/ *omg wow, the site we're discussing this on hosts all it's images on a CDN... must be one of those rare cases*

Comment: @rlemon Must be. You know that the majority of sites on the web are not multi-thousand user-based sites that require load balancing, etc, right? Until the user specifically states their case, any assumption is unfounded (mine included), but it's *safer* to assume that it's a brochure site, small company site, or similar.

Comment: @GregPettit, CDN is very cheap these days and easy to setup. It's almost free if you don't have many visitors. It doesn't matter what the OP has, as my argument was for the general case.

Comment: @GregPettit thats like saying ***until the OP has specified, I can assume this only needs to be compatible with IE6***. The issue is not with your answer not being correct *in some cases*. It is that Esailija has pointed out a case where it *will fail*. Your job as a programmer is to recognize that fact and take the suggestion to improve your own code. Scale-ability mean anything to you? Arguing a moot point that you *don't think it is necessarily good practice to host static content on a CDN if your traffic is low* is just silly.

Comment: @Esailija You're not a hack just because you're realistic about your site's traffic and don't require a CDN for most of your cases. Some of us also build web applications that are self-contained and cannot use a CDN. We're not all writing the next StackOverflow. ;-) I understand your point, but I simply think it was overstated.

Comment: @rlemon Troll much? Not interested.

Comment: @GregPettit no trying to push the point that your ideas about a CDN and when it should be used is wrong. don't want other users reading this and getting the wrong idea.

Comment: @rlemon You need to read more critically. I was not pushing people away from using a CDN. My goal was actually the same as yours: it's not correct information to say that images are "usually" stored on a CDN. And it's not responsible to imply that all people doing web development had better be using a CDN. There are many use cases in which it is not only a questionable "requirement" but could be a detriment or liability. I don't want others to read this and get the wrong idea. For the record, I did like Esailija's answer best...

Comment: @GregPettit, you don't get it. You are by "definition", "hacking around", if you expect your site to never grow or don't need to think about scalability. If you suddenly need to accommodate to a increasing visitor count, good luck replacing all the hacks that were good enough for your locahost machine.

Comment: @GregPettit then your point was lost. Most sites (that are viewed) **do** use a CDN to host static content. *And* it is a good idea to use a CDN to host static content for performance reasons. But this has gotten off topic.

Comment: You will likely want to add async:false on the AJAX call, otherwise the return timing can be suspect and cause unexpected script behavior.

Answer (score 5):

```
$("#image").bind("error", function () {
    $(this).remove();
}).prop("src", src);
```

If this causes an error (as in javascript error) upgrade your jQuery or use the sinful:

```
$("#image").bind("error", function () {
    $(this).remove();
}).attr("src", src);
```

Comment: I quite like this in theory (haven't tried it in practice yet)! I never think to bind error events.

Comment: I like this because it is straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

There's a way to handle errors on IMG tags. 
Something like this:

```
<img src="image.png" OnError="this.src='';"/>
```

Comment: JavaScript events at this level are considered pretty bad practice, although I suppose there's always room to make an exception. More importantly, though, the original question shows some sort of expression being used to set image source with logic; it's not simply an image tag.

Comment: So if the image is not found you decide to load the entire page? http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/11/30/empty-image-src-can-destroy-your-site/ Since the page is not an image, it will probably cause a funny infinite loop but I haven't really tested it :D

Answer (score 1):

You can check status code from ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    statusCode: {
        404: function() {
            alert('not found');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: For specifically checking if the image is found or not, this is a better solution than using the error callback. Reason being, error will pop for any kind of error, and the above is specifically for "resource not found".

Answer (score 1):

check if your images exists before you start the js script so something like:

**UPDATED:**

Assuming `data.image` already come from such kind of json responce.

check if image exists before send it, `if( !file_exists('image.jpg') { $data = array('images' => 'false', 'foo' => 'bar', ... ) }`

then inside the `$.ajax();` call check it if `data.image != 'false'`

Answer (score 1):

If you create a javascript variable `var image = new Image();` you can then attach a onload or onerror event handler on it. You will be able to tell if the image you are changing too is invalid before you change it.

```
function ChangeImage() {

    var image= new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
        alert('loaded');
    };
    image.onerror = function() {
        alert('error loading');
    };
    image.src = "http://BrokenPath/Sterling.jpg"
}
```

[See this fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/VRNmW/12/)

Answer (score 0):

you can attach a handler to the onerror event

Comment: @Beginner See my Answer for example